# Horizon detection

Tags: image-processing, hough-transform

Hi
How is the Hough transform used to detect the horizon in an image? How can we use texture information in images?

Comment: The MATLAB documentation of the Hough transform is really good. It also explains how it works. http://www.mathworks.de/help/toolbox/images/ref/hough.html

Answer (score 1):

The Hough transform is used to detect straight lines in an image. The transform is most useful when you preprocess the image using an edge filter like Prewitt or Canny. Type "help hough" in Matlab for some simple examples. If you can find two sets of lines in the image which are known to be the image projections of parallel lines that lie on the ground plane in world coordinates then the intersection points of these lines in image coordinates when joined together will define your horizon line.